# Converting ChartJSCore to Highcharts.net - issue with dynamic series data in a loop

Tags: asp.net, .net, highcharts, chart.js

(As I've answered my question, this is an edit to let people know that creating a dynamic number columns or bars in a stacked bar or stacked column chart can be achieved using ChartJSCore or HighCharts.Net using the appropriate solutions below. I hope this helps someone.)

I've hit a roadblock with ChartJS with regard to chart legends in general and with its implementation of stacked bar charts, so I had to find another alternative. Highcharts.NET looks great and is rather easy to implement if your data is static, but when is our data static. They don't include any dynamic examples and there aren't any examples online here on Stackoverflow.

In ChartJSCore creating a series of data sets in a loop is rather easy.

This code works fine for ChartJSCore:

```
IDictionary<string, BarDataset> barDataset = new Dictionary<string, BarDataset>();
            data.Datasets = new List<Dataset>();
            //assign series totals to the chart's dataset
            foreach (var seriesId in seriesIds)
            {
                var seriesName = _seriesRepository.GetSeriesName(seriesId);
                var seriesTotalsByLast6Months = _seriesRepository.GetSeriesTotalsByLast6Months(seriesId);
                barDataset[seriesId.ToString()] = new BarDataset
                {
                    Data = seriesTotalsByLast6Months.Select(x => x.Amount).ToArray(),
                    Label = seriesName.First()
                };
            }

            //Add the datasets to the dataset list
            foreach (var x in barDataset.Values)
            {
                data.Datasets.Add(x);
            }
```

I'm heading this direction, but there's a type mismatch on the Data = seriesTotalsByLast6Months.Select(x => x.Amount).ToList() line because HighCharts won't accept a Generic list. It has its own list and I don't know how to format it in this context.

```
IDictionary<string, ColumnSeries> columnSeries = new Dictionary<string, ColumnSeries>();

            foreach (var seriesId in seriesIds)
            {
                var seriesName = _seriesRepository.GetSeriesName(seriesId);
                var seriesTotalsByLast6Months = _seriesRepository.GetSeriesTotalsByLast6Months(seriesId);
                columnSeries[seriesId.ToString()] = new ColumnSeries
                {
                    Name = seriesName.First(),
                    //type mismatch on the line below
                    Data = seriesTotalsByLast6Months.Select(x => x.Amount).ToList()
                };
            }


            foreach (var x in columnSeries.Values)
            {
                //also, what goes here - what do you add the columnSeries' to?
            }
```

Also, have no idea what the loop to add the composed datasets looks like. In ChartJSCore, you have to create a Data object and add the datasets to that. As my code shows, it's rather easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem thusly, because the HighChart data expects its own formatted ColumnSeriesData - for whatever strange reason the devs decided to do this, you can't pass in a generic list:

```
IDictionary<string, ColumnSeries> columnSeries = new Dictionary<string, ColumnSeries>();

            foreach (var seriesId in seriesIds)
            {
                var seriesName = _seriesRepository.GetSeriesName(seriesId);
                var seriesTotalsByLast6Months = _seriesRepository.GetSeriesTotalsByLast6Months(seriesId);
                List<ColumnSeriesData> columnSeriesData = new List<ColumnSeriesData>();
                seriesTotalsByLast6Months.ForEach(p => columnSeriesData.Add(new ColumnSeriesData { Y = p.Amount }));

                columnSeries[seriesId.ToString()] = new ColumnSeries
                {
                    Name = seriesName.First(),
                    Data = columnSeriesData
                };
            }
```

And for the loop to add the column series data to the chart (where chartOptions is the name of your HighChart):

```
foreach (var x in columnSeries.Values)
            {
                //add column series to the chart
                chartOptions.Series.Add(x);
            }
```